# What would be the best ontology evaluation tool to use to analyse and evaluate the Computer Science Ontology (CSO)?

Tags: tool-request, ontology, analysis

A tool that can assess the effectiveness of the Computer Science Ontology (CSO) in the best possible way, by assessing metrics such as accuracy, completeness, conciseness, consistency, expressiveness and other key factors that can be analysed and evaluated to assess the overall effectiveness of the ontology in representing the computer science domain.

I wish to evaluate the ontology on criteria such as accuracy, completeness, conciseness, consistency, expressiveness, computational efficiency and practical usefulness as a representation of the computer science domain.

Comment: I don't think this is a question that can be answered in general. This question can only be answered wrt specific use cases. Hence, the question you need to ask first is "What use cases am I interested in?". Then, based on those use cases, you can evaluate it regarding the criteria you specified.

Comment: I wish to evaluate the ontology on criteria such as accuracy, completeness, conciseness, consistency, expressiveness, computational efficiency and practical usefulness as a representation of the computer science domain.

Comment: For that you still need specific use cases. Computer Science is a vast field. You need to identify the specific use cases within the field of Computer Science you are interested in.

Comment: I understand, thank you. I am just curious as I was thinking there would be a tool that would be able to evaluate the ontology in regards to how accurately represent the computer science domain. Just primarily the main issue is most tools are not compatible with the CSO as its made of one class and a bunch of individuals. To be fair I am also wondering what would be the best factor to evaluate within the ontology as I am not to clear on that myself. However, thank you I will look into use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Well yeah CSO is not an ontology but a thesaurus.

Here's an idea: compare it to Microsoft Academic Graph's "Fields of Science".

Also, you need to include some actual papers in your study, indexed with the two, and assess the accuracy/adequacy of indexing with the two topic thesauri.